# How to convert output exec command to json in golang

Tags: json, go, exec

I have use `exec.Command(command)` on golang and convert it to string.
When I RunCommand `systeminfo` on windowOS it return string type `key:value`. How to convert it to json?

[image]

Code:

```
// Version Function:
func Version() (version string) {
    os := OS()
    if os == "macOS X" {
        result := RunCommand("sw_vers")
        resultRune := []rune(result)
        version = string(resultRune[38:43]) // tested
    }
    if os == "Windows" {
        result := RunCommand("systeminfo")
        resultRune := []rune(result)
        version = string(resultRune[:]) // not tested
    }
    if os == "Linux" {
        result := RunCommand("lsb_release -a")
        resultRune := []rune(result)
        version = string(resultRune[:]) // not tested
    }
    return version
}
// RunCommand Function:
func RunCommand(command string) string {
    cmd := exec.Command(command)
    var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &stdout
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Command "+command+" failed with %s\n", err)
    }
    outStr := string(stdout.Bytes())
    return outStr
}
```

Comment: What is that OS() function doing actually? You can use   `runtime.GOOS` for checking the OS type.

Comment: Yep. this is runtime.GOOS 
```
// OS Function:
func OS() (os string) {

 switch goos := runtime.GOOS; goos {
 case "darwin":
  os = "macOS X"
 case "windows":
  os = "Windows"
 case "linux":
  os = "Linux"
 default:
  os = "unknown"
 }

 return os
}
```

Comment: If it returns a map, use json.Marshal to convert it to JSON. You mean stdout returns a map on Windows? I can't test it on Windows.

Comment: It looks like a map but not a map.

Comment: It takes the form: 
ProductName: Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15
BuildVersion: 19A501i